# how to test one-hot Vs. label-encoder in gradient boosting sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've done some research about this matter. Most of people argue which one to use in gradient boosting. https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/discussion/59873 Most kagglers here explain that label encoder is used or ordinal values and one-hot for categorical.

ex: genius, smart, less-smart should be label encoded into genius=3, smart=2, and less-smart=1.

However according to sklearn documentation, label encoding is only used for target values. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

So I've trained a model by converting one of my feature using one-hot and label encoder to see which would predict better. 
(according to sklearn doc, label encoder should be used for target values. In my case it is wrong since I've used it on one of my independent variable(x)?)

First, using label encoder.

```
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

label_encoder.fit(data_set["region"])
data_set['region'] = label_encoder.transform(data_set["region"])

X, y = data_set.iloc[:, 1:6], data_set.iloc[:,-1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

gbr_le = GradientBoostingRegressor(
    n_estimators  = 1000,
    learning_rate = 0.1,
    random_state  = 0
)

model = gbr_le.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(f'RMSE with label encoding (best_num_trees) = {np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))}')

>>> RMSE with label encoding (best_num_trees) = 4.881378370139346
```

Now this time using one-hot

```
regions = pd.get_dummies(data_set_onehot.region)
data_set_onehot.drop(columns=['region'], inplace=True)
X, y = data_set_onehot.iloc[:, 1:5], data_set_onehot.iloc[:,-1]
X = pd.concat([X, regions], axis=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

gbr_onehot = GradientBoostingRegressor(
    n_estimators  = 1000,
    learning_rate = 0.1,
    random_state  = 0
)
model = gbr_onehot.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(f'RMSE with one-hot encoding (best_num_trees) = {np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))}')

>>> RMSE with one-hot encoding (best_num_trees) = 4.86943654679908
```

This time model trained after using one-hot gave better rmse score. I don't think I can judge since depending on random_state value on either train_test_split, GradientBoostingRegressor changes RMSE value.

What would be best way to measure better accuracy between two model with different feature processing?

Comment: If you have the time just train both e.g. 100 times and take the average accuracy for each? If needed just put it in a loop and let it run overnight?

Comment: Yes I can do that but was just wondering if there were alternative method since it seems inefficient.

Comment: be careful that label encoding should be done after splitting the data into train and test sets, not before, to avoid target leakage. Here's an explanation of the steps for cross-validation: https://www.kaggle.com/c/the-analytics-edge-mit-15-071x/discussion/7837 and https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/political-analysis/article/how-crossvalidation-can-go-wrong-and-what-to-do-about-it/CA8C4B470E27C99892AB978CE0A3AE29/core-reader. There's a `pipeline` object to handle this and chain preprocessing and model training in the same CV procedure https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html

Comment: Are we allowed to use label encoding on our features?? On the second line of doc it says to use it on target values.